# SQL Update with Join and Sub Query

Tags: performance, t-sql

I have the following queries and have trouble putting them together:

```
DECLARE @Value1 INT = 3
DECLARE @Value2 INT = 6

UPDATE TableA SET 
        Column1 = B.NewValue,
FROM TableA A   INNER JOIN TableB B ON A.NumberId = B.NumberId AND 
AND A.Type = @Value1

UPDATE TableA SET 
        Column2 = B.NewValue,
FROM TableA A INNER JOIN TableB B ON A.NumberId = B.NumberId AND 
AND A.Type = @Value2
```

My goal is to have one query with a join that updates the columns depending on the values in the join.
This I just an example (in my case there are more columns and therefore more queries) but overall I want to have as few queries as possible (in this example: one query instead of two)

```
DECLARE @Value1 INT = 3
DECLARE @Value2 INT = 6

UPDATE TableA SET 
        Column1 = B.NewValue,  --if the join joins on @Value1
        Column2 = B.NewValue,  --if the join joins on @Value2
FROM TableA A   INNER JOIN TableB B ON A.NumberId = B.NumberId AND 
AND A.Type = B.@Value1/@Value2
```

Is this possible (using a sub query for example)?

Comment: T-SQL is used by several products such as (but not limited to), Sybase, SQL Server, and Azure Synapse. What (R)DBMS are you using?

Comment: "if the join joins on @Value1" As you are user `INNER JOIN`s then the `JOIN` *must* happen. Are you, therefore, actually after `LEFT JOIN`s? Is so, what happens if a value in the other table isn't found?

Comment: I also feel like your simplification may hide the actual problem some what. If you can provide details of the actual logic and goal, along with meaningful sample data (and expected results) that might better explain the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using `CASE EXPRESSION`

```
UPDATE TableA SET 
        Column1 = CASE WHEN A.Type = @Value1 THEN B.NewValue 
                       ELSE A.Column1 END, 
        Column2 = CASE WHEN A.Type = @Value2 THEN B.NewValue 
                       ELSE A.Column2 END 
FROM TableA A INNER JOIN TableB B ON A.NumberId = B.NumberId AND 
AND A.Type IN (@Value1, @Value2)
```